# How to replace columns names based on a column_map objects between two dataframes in R

Tags: r, names

I have two data frames and I need replace the column names of the first dataset based on a `column_map` that describes a mapping to replace column names.

Here is how my sample dataset looks like.

```
  dat.1 <- data.frame(column_1 = c(1:5),
                      column_2 = c(1:5),
                      column_3 = c(1:5),
                      column_4 = c(1:5))

> dat.1
  column_1 column_2 column_3 column_4
1        1        1        1        1
2        2        2        2        2
3        3        3        3        3
4        4        4        4        4
5        5        5        5        5

dat.2 <- data.frame(column_1a = c(1:5),
                    column_2b = c(1:5),
                    column_3c = c(1:5))

> dat.2
  column_1a column_2b column_3c
1         1         1         1
2         2         2         2
3         3         3         3
4         4         4         4
5         5         5         5

column_map <- data.frame(name.1 = c("column_1", "column_2", "column_3"),
                         name.2 = c("column_1a", "column_2b", "column_3c"))

> column_map
    name.1    name.2
1 column_1 column_1a
2 column_2 column_2b
3 column_3 column_3c
```

So, for example, I need to switch `column_1` in `dat.1` to `column_1a` and so on based on the column_map.

Edit: I would like to keep the fourth column `column_4` as it is since it is not mapped (no equivalence in the second dataset).

The desired output would be:

```
> dat.1
  column_1a column_2b column_3c column_4
1         1         1         1     1
2         2         2         2     2
3         3         3         3     3
4         4         4         4     4
5         5         5         5     5
```

Thanks for looking into this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like that.

```
colnames(dat.1) <- column_map[match(colnames(dat.1), column_map[,1]), 2]

> dat.1
  column_1a column_2b column_3c
1         1         1         1
2         2         2         2
3         3         3         3
4         4         4         4
5         5         5         5
```

EDIT:

Regarding your edit you can use `setnames()` from `data.table`-package.

```
setnames(dat.1, old = column_map$name.1, new = column_map$name.2, skip_absent = T)

> dat.1
  column_1a column_2b column_3c column_4
1         1         1         1        1
2         2         2         2        2
3         3         3         3        3
4         4         4         4        4
5         5         5         5        5
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I added another column in the first dataset which is not in the mapping data frame. Is there a way to keep that column and change the names of the rest?

Comment: thanks for your time!